# Javascript `filter` + `reduce` VS `reduce` + `if`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

```
Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (someCondition(key, value)) {
    acc[key] = value;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});


Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([key, value]) => someCondition(key, value))
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

The above two blocks do the same thing: create a copy of `obj` with some properties removed based on `someCondition`.

Which way is preferred and why?

Comment: The one that is easier to understand. Just yesterday, I’ve used a `reduce`–`if` in an answer of mine, where _two_ arrays had to be processed together, instead of just one, so the use-case was a bit more complex.

Comment: The second creates two "copies" (`filter` + `reduce`) vs. one in the first (`reduce`).

Comment: `filter` then `reduce` is a bit more clear but also has a cost : O(n*m) (max is O(n²)). Where `reduce` with `if` statement has a cost of O(n).

Comment: @Vivick Nope - it's `O(n+m)` at best

Comment: @Vivick How has `filter` then `reduce` a higher time complexity?! It’s O(n + m), if anything.

Comment: Totally opinion based. That said, I'd personally pick the second one, since it's more separated. The filter code is separate from the aggregation code.

Comment: @Xufox it is always O(n+m) but if there was no removal then it is O(2n)

Comment: The `reduce` in first one does twice the amount of work compare to the `reduce` in second one due to the condition checking. So wouldn't the work done between first and second be the same (both O(2n))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It always depends.

With the first case - `reduce` with condition inside - you'll loop your dataset just once.

Second case gives you two loops (second works on limited dataset) but the code is much more readable and operations are separated (filtering / modifying data).

Comment: btw first case also may run once if you use some library that supports lazy evaluation(like lazy.js or lodash)

Comment: First case requires 1 additional operation on each iteration (condition check) compare to second case, so wouldn't the total work done be similar?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer either the completely imperative approach

```
function filterProperties(obj, predicate) {
    const res = {};
    for (const key in obj) {
        const val = obj[key];
        if (predicate(key, var))
            res[key] = val; 
    }
    return res;
}
```

or the completely functional approach

```
function filterProperties(obj, predicate) {
    return fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(entry => predicate(...entry)));
}
function fromEntries(entries) {
    const res = {};
    for (const [key, val] of entries) // using `reduce` is not much of an advantage here
        res[key] = val;
    return res;
}
```